# c++ AMP template specific restrict

Tags: c++, templates, c++-amp

I have a problem of design in the following code. The Idea I have is to have a Data class, that has 2 nested classes GPU and Process. 
GPU Contains the datas transfered to GPU ... and Process, processes the datas with the same code on CPU and GPU.

```cpp
#include <amp.h>

class Data
{
public:

   template <class DataToProcess>
   class Process
   {
   public:
      Process(const DataToProcess &pp): p(pp){};

      // Here is the problem ... I want operator() to be restrict(amp) if DataToProcess is Data::GPU and restrict(cpu) if DataToProcess is Data
      float operator()() const restrict(amp, cpu)
      { // do stuff
      }


  private:
      DataToProcess p;
  };

  class GPU
  {
  public:
      // Constructor transfers vectors and other datas to GPU
      GPU(Data& host) : d(host.d), f(host.f){}

      const Process<Data::GPU> getProcessor() const { return Data::Process<Data::GPU>(*this); }

  public:
      concurrency::array_view<float>    d;
      float                             f;
  };



public:

  Data(){}
  const Process<Data> getProcessor() const { return Process<Data>(*this); }
  GPU TransferToGPU()
  {
      // Construct the gpu object
      GPU gpu(*this);

      // Returns it
      return gpu;
  }

public:
  std::vector<float>    d;
  float                 f;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Data d;
   Data::GPU dgpu = d.TransferToGPU();

   auto p1 = d.getProcessor();
   auto p2 = dgpu.getProcessor();

   return 0;
}
```

I am now stucked at the definition of the operator(), because wher I apply it to Data, it needs restrict(cpu) and when I apply it to Data::GPU, it needs restrict(amp).

Is there any may to make it work ?

I read in AMP documentation that a restrict(auto) could appear one day. I think this would fit my needs.

**EDIT**

Thank's to ForEveR and for those interested I arrived to a solution I find dirty. But that fits to my needs.

The idea is to use SFINAE as pointed ForEveR, but to define them in an old style macro so that I can use that in all my classes that uses this structure.

Here is the code :

```
#define MyOperator( compute_method ) \
template< typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<DataToProcess, Data>::value>::type>\
float operator()() const restrict(cpu)\
{\
    compute_method \
}\
template< typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<DataToProcess, Data::GPU>::value>::type>\
float operator()() const restrict(amp)\
{\
    compute_method\
}



class Data
{
public:

    class GPU;

    template <class DataToProcess>
    class Process
    {
    public:
        Process(const DataToProcess &pp)
            : p(pp)
        {

        };

        MyOperator(
            int ab = 0;
            return ab;
            )

    private:
        DataToProcess   p;
    };

    class GPU
    {
    public:
        // Constructor transfers vectors and other datas to GPU
        GPU(Data& host)
            : d(host.d)
            , f(host.f)
        {}

        const Process<Data::GPU> getProcessor() const { return Data::Process<Data::GPU>(*this); }

    public:
        concurrency::array_view<float>      d;      //< The different stacks of medium
        float                               f;          //< The current frequency being processed by the stacks

    };



public:

    Data(){}

    const Process<Data> getProcessor() const { return Process<Data>(*this); }

    GPU TransferToGPU()
    {
        // Construct the gpu object
        GPU gpu(*this);

        // Returns it
        return gpu;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // Private members
    // ------------------------------------------------
public:
    std::vector<float>      d;          //< The different stacks of medium
    float                   f;          //< The current frequency being processed by the stacks

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Data d;
    Data::GPU d_gpu = d.TransferToGPU();

    auto p = d.getProcessor();
    auto p_gpu = d_gpu.getProcessor();

    p();
    p_gpu();    // This line does not compile as p_gpu is amp restricted, that is what we want

    return 0;
}
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do that, but until now I did not find.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such thing using SFINAE with type_traits in C++11.

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<DataToProcess, Data>::value, float>::type
operator()() const restrict(cpu)
{ 
   // do stuff
}

typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<DataToProcess, Data::GPU>::value, float>::type
operator()() const restrict(amp)
{ 
   // do stuff
}
```

Don't forget to forward declare `GPU` class.

Comment: Thank's for the fast answer. What if I do not want to duplicate my code. In this example, do stuff is exactly the same for cpu and gpu

Comment: @RaF as I can see, you can write helper function, that can be
`float process() const restrict(amp, cpu)` and call it from your operator.

Comment: Yep, but `float process()` has no informations on `DataToProcess p`, and `template <class DataToProcess> float process(DataToProcess &p)` will result to the same restriction problems  ...

Comment: @RaF no, look at my answer.

Comment: your solution will not compile because `float process() const restrict(amp, cpu)` has acces to  `DataToProcess p`  with `DataToProcess` = `Data` and is not amp compatible type.

Comment: @RaF than just write two versions without helper.

Comment: The aim of this structure was to build a generic code for the processing. But OK I think I will have to duplicate the same code twice until `restrict(auto)` arrives. Thank you.